# Access site from public ip

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

When I debug my asp.net mvc3 web application on `http://localhost:11118/` using microsoft visual studio and it works perfectly.

But when I try to view it on `http://MYPUBLICIPADRESS:11118/` I get a `HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.` message. I portforwarded port 1118 correctly. I have no problems doing the same using apache.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Is that port open on windows firewall on that machine?

Comment: @levelnis Yes, I disabled my firewall completely just to make sure its not a problem. Also made myself the DMZ host so all my ports are open in the router settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio internal server only accepts connection coming from `localhost`. You should use IIS Express (and manually change the config file) to let it accept connection using other hostnames, including the computer name.

You can read more about setting the server of your preferences [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks dude, that makes sense. However, does that mean its not possible to show someone else the site while im working on it in visual studio?

Comment: You can, but only using IIS Express or a proper IIS instance. Another option would be to google for a cheap or free Windows hosting. I've added a link to MSDN on how to configure your favourite server.

Comment: You could also sign up for a free Azure Websites account. Couple that with Git hosting on Bitbucket and you can push changes to Bitbucket and have Azure deploy your site automatically

Comment: That was my idea too but did not want to do any advertising :) anyway yes, Azure is a good way to go (but the db is not free after the 90 days trial in case you need hat as well).